# How to edit (fetch/store) with Summernote textarea + Datastore GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, summernote

Until recently I was able to post data to my datastore (Google App Engine). I've now added summernote wysiwyg and now I'm no longer able to add/fetch data from the datastore. Where do you think the problem is?

**Main.py**

```
class About(ndb.Model):
   text = ndb.StringProperty()

  #object   
   cv = About()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    title="Exercise"
    cv = About.get_or_insert('6684480941064192')
    text = cv.text

    template_vars={'title': title, 'text':text}
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('home.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_vars))

def post(self):
    cv = About.get_or_insert('6684480941064192')
    cv.text=self.request.get("texto")
    cv.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

**Html** (Material design + bootstrp)

```
<form class="col s12" form action="/"  method="POST" id="frmPost" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="panel panel-heading" style ="border-radius: 0px; background-color: #e57373;">
                <h3 class="panel-title" style ="color: white;">About...</h3>
            </div>

            <textarea rows="10" id="summernote" form="frmPost" name ="texto" style="margin-top:-10px; display:block;">
                    {{text}}
            </textarea>

        </div>


</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `summernote` is but you probably need to `POST` your data back to the server somewhere in your HTML/JS. You have the `<form>` but there doesn't seem to be a way to submit your data back to GAE. You possibly need something like `<input type="submit" value="Save Data" />` somewhere inside your `<form/>`.

Comment: Hi @Mihail Russu. The submit button is there. I just did not show it here.     <button id="btn_cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default button-group pull-right save-action">Cancel</button> .

Comment: Is the request being sent to GAE (you can see it in Chrome's DevTools)? Is the request being processed by GAE? Can you debug/log the handling and post the results here?

Comment: let me trace it out in the dev tools and revert asap. Thanks